# how to connect DV code embedded inside an RTL module to the testbench

Tags: system-verilog

I have to embed DV code inside an RTL module for verification purposes. There are many (1000s) of instances of this RTL module.  How do I make it controllable on a per instance basis from the test? Testbench is in SystemVerilog UVM.  I want to stay away from CDPI?

Any suggestions would be appreciated

-Hawki

Answer (score 1):

You use the `bind` construct to insert a module or interface into your RTL module. Inside this bound module you construct a class with methods that interact with your RTL module. The class object is set into the uvm_config_db for each instance. Then your testbench gets these objects from the uvm_config_db and you can call those object methods from the testbench.

I wrote a DVCon 2012 paper [The Missing Link: The Testbench to DUT Connection](http://events.dvcon.org/2012/proceedings/papers/01P_3.pdf) with a complete example for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave described in his answer, `bind` statements are usually the best way to go.

Though there are other ways as well, which might be more convenient in some cases. They are based on parameterized modules.

1) direct instantiation with parameters

```
 module rtl #(bit dvflag = 0) ();
    ...
    if (dvflag)
       dv_module dv_instance(...);
    ...
endmodule


module dut;
   rtl  rtl1();
   rtl #(.dvflag(1)) rtl2();
   ...
endmodule
```

2) Overwriting instances with v2k config statements.

```
module dut;
   rtl rtl1();
   rtl rtl2();
endmodule
...

config dv_cfg;
     instance dut.rtl2 use #(.dvflag(1));
     ...
 endocnfig
```